# Mongodb University aggregation practice lab: understanding $sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am doing Mongodb university introductory course and i am on aggreagation section. Practice lab asks to sort data to find the birds that are sighted furthest North.

The question is: i get the exact same result for both longitude and latitude for ascending and descending orders, nothing changes at the prompt. I could not understand what is wrong about the query. Is it related to location related sorting issue or query is just wrong.

Sample document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("62cf8ebfbb9cdbee29caab04"),
  species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
  species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
  date: ISODate("2022-01-18T21:09:00.000Z"),
  location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 40, -74 ] }
}
```

If i get it correctly, location field is a kind of special field to form points, lines, coordinates etc. Type of "point" is formed as first latitude then longitude data. Lab's solved code is: (i changed the limit to 6, it is actually 4 on the original recommended code)

```
db.sightings.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
        'location.latitude': -1
    }
  }, {
    $limit: 6
  }
])
```

And the output is:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62cf32bdcfe5bbb25ee815fc"),
    species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
    species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-18T18:24:00.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 40, -73 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62cf2f0acfe5bbb25ee815fb"),
    species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
    species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-17T18:24:00.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 41, -74 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62cf8eb2bb9cdbee29caab03"),
    species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
    species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-18T23:55:40.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 40, -74 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62cf8ebfbb9cdbee29caab04"),
    species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
    species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-18T21:09:00.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 40, -74 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62cf8e9fbb9cdbee29caab02"),
    species_common: 'Eastern Bluebird',
    species_scientific: 'Sialia sialis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-18T18:22:20.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 40, -74 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62e2d811b1d5bc85b6e04013"),
    species_common: 'Northern Cardinal',
    species_scientific: 'Cardinalis Cardinalis',
    date: ISODate("2022-01-18T05:30:40.000Z"),
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 41, -74 ] }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting on a field that does not exist.

The dot notation "location.latitude" is expecting the 'location' to contain a document with a 'latitude' field.

The document in the location field has only a 'type' field containing a string and a 'coordinates' field containing an array of integers.

In GeoJSON notation, the first coordinate will be longitude and the second latitude, so you can refer to the value in the array using dot notation:

```
{$sort: {"location.coordinates.1": -1}}
```

Comment: For future reference: maybe the collection is updated but solution code is outdated. When i first saw the solution code, i read GeoJSON documentation that says longitude first, second is the latitude: it made me think that it is a special way to access those coordinates as `coordinates.longitude` and `coordinates.latitude`.